# Ipad landscape splash won't show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to set a Landscape splash for my iPad app but it's not working.

I currently have a Default-Landscape.png and a Default-Portrait.png.
I added the four orientation in my plist file and still nothing.

It works if I launch in portrait, but if I launch in Landscape the screen stay black until my app start.

Is there anything else to do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

If you've made sure that Default-Landscape.png is actually in your application's bundle (try to readd it), made sure there was no Default.png, and added all 4 orientations in "supported interface orientations" in the plist and *saved* it; it should work as expected.

Comment: There must be something wrong in my code then.. Thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: Damn I found out my problem! My Default-Landscape.png image was 5.7mb so I guess it was taking too long to load the image and the app was launching before. I compressed the image and it's now working!